# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration'

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I developed a microservice application with JHipster, separating the client-side and server-side components. After completing the development, I deployed the gateway as a .war file to install it on an external Tomcat server. However, I encountered an exception.

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

[Here is the complete exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ttWD.png)

Here is the code for the pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xtensus.postariongateway</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>${caffeine.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>blockhound-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${blockhound-junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit5-api</artifactId>
            <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit-junit5-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security OAuth 2.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-jcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-webclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-cloud</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-spring-configuration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.27.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources/config</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                            <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>io.spring.nohttp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>nohttp-checkstyle</artifactId>
                            <version>${nohttp-checkstyle.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                        <includes>pom.xml,README.md</includes>
                        <excludes>.git/**/*,target/**/*,node_modules/**/*,node/**/*</excludes>
                        <sourceDirectories>./</sourceDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-war</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceIncludes>WEB-INF/**,META-INF/**</warSourceIncludes>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${properties-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>sonar-project.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${git-commit-id-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>revision</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                        <failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>false</failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>
                        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                        <includeOnlyProperties>
                            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.abbrev$</includeOnlyProperty>
                            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.commit.id.describe$</includeOnlyProperty>
                            <includeOnlyProperty>^git.branch$</includeOnlyProperty>
                        </includeOnlyProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.gaul</groupId>
                    <artifactId>modernizer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${modernizer-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>modernizer</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>modernizer</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <javaVersion>${java.version}</javaVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-integration-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-integration-tests</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>
                            <image>${jib-maven-plugin.image}</image>
                            <platforms>
                                <platform>
                                    <architecture>${jib-maven-plugin.architecture}</architecture>
                                    <os>linux</os>
                                </platform>
                            </platforms>
                        </from>
                        <to>
                            <image>postariongateway:latest</image>
                        </to>
                        <container>
                            <entrypoint>
                                <shell>bash</shell>
                                <option>-c</option>
                                <arg>/entrypoint.sh</arg>
                            </entrypoint>
                            <ports>
                                <port>8583</port>
                            </ports>
                            <environment>
                                <SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>ALWAYS</SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>
                                <JHIPSTER_SLEEP>0</JHIPSTER_SLEEP>
                            </environment>
                            <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                            <user>1000</user>
                        </container>
                        <extraDirectories>
                            <paths>src/main/docker/jib</paths>
                            <permissions>
                                <permission>
                                    <file>/entrypoint.sh</file>
                                    <mode>755</mode>
                                </permission>
                            </permissions>
                        </extraDirectories>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-site-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-versions</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-dependencyConvergence</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <DependencyConvergence />
                                </rules>
                                <fail>false</fail>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-idea-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <exclude>node_modules</exclude>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-resources</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                                <delimiters>
                                    <delimiter>#</delimiter>
                                </delimiters>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>config/*.yml</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>config/*.yml</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*IT*</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*IntTest*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                               <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/api.yml</inputSpec>
                                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                                <apiPackage>com.xtensus.postariongateway.web.api</apiPackage>
                                <modelPackage>com.xtensus.postariongateway.service.api.dto</modelPackage>
                                <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                <importMappings>Problem=org.zalando.problem.Problem</importMappings>
                                <skipValidateSpec>false</skipValidateSpec>
                                <configOptions>
                                    <reactive>false</reactive>
                                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                    <title>post-arion-gateway</title>
                                </configOptions>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*IT*</include>
                                    <include>**/*IntTest*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```